# python slicing does not give key error even when the column is missing

Tags: python, pandas, object-slicing

I have a pandas dataframe with 10 keys. If I try to access a column that is not present, even then it returns a NaN for this. I was expecting a KeyError. How is pandas not able to identify the missing column ?

In the example below, vendor_id is a valid column in dataframe. The other column is absent from the dataset.

```
final_feature.ix[:,['vendor_id','this column is absent']]
Out[1017]: 
  vendor_id  this column is absent
0    434236                    NaN

type(final_feature)
Out[1016]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

EDIT 1: Validated that no null values are there

```
print (final_feature1.isnull().values.any())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour and is due to the feature [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement)

```
In [15]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
df.ix[:,['a','d']]

Out[15]:
          a   d
0 -1.164349 NaN
1  0.400116 NaN
2 -0.599496 NaN
3  0.186837 NaN
4  0.385656 NaN
```

If you try `df['d']` or `df[['a','d']]`  then you will get a `KeyError`

Effectively what you're doing is reindexing, the fact the column doesn't exists when using `ix` doesn't matter, you'll just get a column of `NaN`s

Same behaviour is observed using `loc`:

```
In [24]:
df.loc[:,['a','d']]

Out[24]:
          a   d
0 -1.164349 NaN
1  0.400116 NaN
2 -0.599496 NaN
3  0.186837 NaN
4  0.385656 NaN
```

When you don't use `ix` or `loc` and try to do `df['d']` you're trying to index a specific column or list of columns, there is no expectation of enlargement here unless you are assigning to a new column: e.g. `df['d'] = some_new_vals`

To guard against this you can validate your list using `isin` with the columns:

```
In [26]:
valid_cols = df.columns.isin(['a','d'])
df.ix[:, valid_cols]

Out[26]:
          a
0 -1.164349
1  0.400116
2 -0.599496
3  0.186837
4  0.385656
```

Now you will only see columns that exist, plus if you have mis-spelt any columns then it will also guard against this

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you suggest removing all instances of .ix from the code? A spelling mistake is how I ran into this issue

Comment: It will work until some future version, from version 0.20.1 it's been marked for deprecation but it still works. The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix) show how to achieve the same behaviour but the behaviour will still happen as I've demonstrated with `loc` but using `isin` against your existing columns will protect against this

Comment: Thanks. I will keep that check in place.

Answer (score 1):

For me works select by `subset`:

```
final_feature[['vendor_id','this column is absent']]
```

> KeyError: "['this column is absent'] not in index"

Also `ix` is deprecated in last version of pandas (`0.20.1`), [check here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix).

Comment: should not it say "['this column is absent'] is not in columns ?

Comment: A dataframe's columns are an index (along axis 1).

Comment: Maybe yes, but I think it is general error for index and columns missing values - index on axis 0 is classic index and index on axis 1 is called columns.

Comment: @IanS you are correct. Default (axis = 0) is the traditional index. but, columns are also index, just along axis = 1 in a dataframe.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks.