# Why does DataFrame.loc not throw an exception here?

Tags: pandas

Why does this:

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6]], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,1), (1,2)]))
print(df_data.loc[[(13,37)]])
```

Return a non-existing row filled with `NaN`

```
        0   1   2
13 37 NaN NaN NaN
```

instead of throwing a `KeyError` exception as it would if I tried to access it with `df_data.loc[(13,37)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to ***feature setting with enlargement*** as explained in the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement). Citing from the doc:

> The .loc/[] operations can perform enlargement when setting a
>   non-existant key for that axis.

so, if you want to get a key error, you need to use `df_data.loc[(13,37)]` instead of `df_data.loc[[(13,37)]]`

---

Example:

```
In [24]: df_data
Out[24]: 
     0  1  2
1 1  1  2  3
  2  4  5  6

In [25]: df_data.loc[[(13,37)]]
Out[25]: 
        0   1   2
13 37 NaN NaN NaN

In [26]: df_data.loc[(13,37)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
...
KeyError: 'the label [13] is not in the [index]'
```

Here's a similar discussion: [python slicing does not give key error even when the column is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911115/python-slicing-does-not-give-key-error-even-when-the-column-is-missing)

Comment: Okay, I see. The question came up as I tried select a list of rows based on a list of indices `loc[ [(1,1), (1,2), ..] ]` - that's how I notice this behavior.